# Python - Keras ShapeError using CNN for a 6 Category Classification Problem

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create a CNN to classify between 6 different classes

I have a different script which simply saves the images + labels into lists, then saved to pickle.

My Error is

```
ValueError: Shapes (None, 6) and (None, 100, 100, 1, 6) are incompatible
```

This is how the data is loaded + converted into numpy arrays

```
#Load Saved Data
pickle_in = open("XTrain.pickle","rb")
XTrain = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("XTest.pickle","rb")
XTest = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("yTrain.pickle","rb")
yTrain = pickle.load(pickle_in)

pickle_in = open("yTest.pickle","rb")
yTest = pickle.load(pickle_in)

#Convert To Float to Normalize
XTrain = XTrain.astype('float32')
XTest = XTest.astype('float32')

#Normalize
XTrain = XTrain/255
XTest = XTest/255

#Convert
XTrain = np.array(XTrain)
XTest = np.array(XTest)
yTrain = np.array(yTrain)
yTest = np.array(yTest)

#Categorical
yTrain = to_categorical(yTrain, 6)
yTest = to_categorical(yTest, 6)


Shape of labels is : (2700, 6)
Shape of images is : (2700, 100, 100, 1)
```

And this is my CNN

```
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Dense(512, input_shape=(XTrain.shape), activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(6, activation='softmax')
])

model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(XTrain, yTrain, epochs=50, batch_size=32)
```

What exactly is triggering the error? I'm still learning tensorflow/keras and am following tutorials however they both result in different errors.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 major reasons for this:

- You have to categorically encode your labels (use Label Encoder first then use One Hot Encoder)
- Your `input_shape` is wrong. You are using the 4D shape which should instead be 3D. It should be like this `input_shape=(100,100,1)`